# Capturing video from window pane

Tags: video, reflection

Often when we try to capture video from inside a bus or car with closed windows, it also captures some reflections appearing in the window.
This spoils the video.

Is there any way to remove those reflections or can camera be adjusted to not to capture the reflections?

Answer (score 2):

A polariser might help some, but probably the best thing is to get one of the collapsible, flexible rubber lens hoods. You want something fairly wide angle and fairly long, if you can manage both.

Then hold the end of the lens hood in contact with the window (all the way round). This shades the window inside the hood from light from inside the vehicle, preventing reflections.

With a rubber hood, you can then angle the camera instead of having to be exactly square on to the window. (Bend it too much and the hood may start blocking some of the view, which is why a wider angle than needed is good - it
allows you to angle the camera more before you start seeing the hood in the picture.)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, to stop the reflections, you have to block light around the lens. The simplest method is to use a piece of dark clothing. E.g. if you have a hoodie, hold the camera/mobile up to the window, then cover your head with the article of clothing, bend down to a level with the lens of the camera, and put yourself and the camera as close to the window as you can. This will work in a pinch, but a more long term solution is to use a Lens Hood, like you see on a film camera. The trick is to keep the lens as close to the reflective surface as possible to prevent light reflections from entering the field of view of the lens.